# new URLPattern raises error in react "'URLPattern' is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the `URLPattern` browser api inside of my react app and I am getting an error `Line 9:19:  'URLPattern' is not defined  no-undef`

the breaking code

```
const p = new URLPattern('https://example.com/foo/:image.jpg?*#*');
```

What are my doing wrong? My browser supports this feature.

Comment: That's a linting error. Your linter doesn't seem to know about `URLPattern`, probably because it's experimental. You should typically be able to list it as a global

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLPattern/URLPattern#browser_compatibility does not say that it is experimental

Comment: how do I list this as global?

Comment: Do you not see the flask icon and _"Experimental. Expect behavior to change in the future."_?

Comment: see it now I can't figure out how to add this to the global list in my app I am using create react app

Comment: See the duplicate I linked at the top of your question. See also [Using Global Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-global-variables/) for an alternative